# Stream.of VS Arrays.stream to get an enum from a value

Tags: java, enums, java-8

With Java 8 I found a common way to get an enum from a value, it's using an `Arrays.stream` with a filter on all the enum values, but recently, I came across another way to do it, with `Stream.of`, what is the better way between each other and why? Is there another better way to do it?

Example:

```
public enum Foo {

    BAR_1("Bar 1"),
    BAR_2("Bar 2");

    private String friendlyValue;

    Foo(String friendlyValue){
        this.friendlyValue = friendlyValue;
    }

    public String getFriendlyValue() {
        return friendlyValue;
    }

    public static Foo fromFriendlyValue1(String friendlyValue){
        return Stream.of(Foo.values()).filter(r -> r.getFriendlyValue().equals(friendlyValue)).findFirst().get();
    }

    public static Foo fromFriendlyValue2(String friendlyValue) {
        return Arrays.stream(Foo.values()).filter(r -> r.getFriendlyValue().equals(friendlyValue)).findFirst().get();
    }
}
```

Comment: where is the question? better is off topic **opinion based**, asking for alternatives is off topic as well **recommendations**

Comment: The correct answer ofcourse is just to loop all values doing the comparison, nobody really cares about the processor time lost doing n comparisons , where n is usually less than 10. And you can always refactor it if you happen to get hundreds of constants in you enum.

Comment: `EnumSet.allOf(Foo.class).stream(). …` or just `return friendlyValue.equals(BAR_1.friendlyValue)? BAR_1: friendlyValue.equals(BAR_2.friendlyValue)? BAR_2: null;`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Stream.of is actually using Arrays.stream.

```
public static<T> Stream<T> of(T... values) {
    return Arrays.stream(values);
}
```

So you can directly use Arrays.stream.

Comment: `.valueOf()` is the actual correct answer for a JDK only solution. [`Enums.stringConverter()`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Enums.html#stringConverter(java.lang.Class)) or [`Enums.getIfPresent()`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Enums.html#getIfPresent(java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.String)) is the correct answer if you are using Guava.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson I don't think any of those solve Emilien's problem. He wants to convert a "friendly" (arbitrary) name to an enum. For the methods you suggested, the name must explicitly match the identifier.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is neither. The cleanest, 1337 way is:

```
public enum Foo {

    BAR_1("Bar 1"),
    BAR_2("Bar 2");

    private static class Holder {
        static Map<String, Foo> map = new HashMap<String, Foo>();
    }

    private String friendlyValue;

    Foo(String friendlyValue){
        this.friendlyValue = friendlyValue;
        Holder.map.put(friendlyValue, this);
    }

    public String getFriendlyValue() {
        return friendlyValue;
    }

    public static Foo fromFriendlyValue(String friendlyValue){
        return Holder.map.get(friendlyValue);
    }
}
```

This implementation of `fromFriendlyValue()` has `O(1)` time complexity - ie it performs in constant time no matter how large the number of instances in your enum.

The kung fu here is the use of the [*Initialization-on-demand holder idiom*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization-on-demand_holder_idiom), which neatly side-steps the problem of the initialization rules of an enum while maintaining encapsulation.

Comment: Hmmm nice ! I keep that.

Comment: @EmilienBrigand yeah, you can impress friends and colleagues - not many folks know about this trick :)

Comment: I dont think that lazy initializes? since immediately when Foo is initialized, java will initialize all values for Foo by calling the constructor which will load the Holder and initialize the values?

Comment: yeah confirmed, this will initialize before calling "fromFriendlyValue" ,one below only inits immediately before call.

Comment: @Bohemian You mean your solution performs better at the expense of extra  space? "cleanest" is very opinion based term.

Comment: @MrinalK.Samanta it uses a tiny amount of space - each map entry has a key and value that are references to objects that already exist. Probably less space than the memory consumed in processing the stream of values (which would be allocated and freed every call), and in the byte code for the method. It could feasibly use less space. But the performance of stream is `O(n)` vs this `O(1)` - it's a no brainer AFAICT

Comment: @Bohemian Agreed that overhead of using stream API would be greater if the stream is small (never seen an Enum will more than 20 values). But we really need not to think about execution time differences between O(20) vs. O(1) with modern jvms (unless it is extreme scenario).

Comment: What is wrong with `.valueOf()`? Why all the acrobatics?

Comment: @JarrodRoberson, that only works if you are looking up the enum by its constant name, not by some other `String` property.

Comment: Why the downvotes? I'm genuinely puzzled... Is this answer not useful?

Comment: it does not do what you say it does and it is complex

Comment: For the case of an `enum`  with two constants (and most other real life `enum`s) the `Map`does not really pay off compared to a simple linear search. I’m also not sure whether the introduction of an additional nested class plus having to change the constructor, just for helping out a single method’s implementation really is the “cleanest” way.

Comment: @Holger firstly, it is common for enums to have "code" they are "serialized" to, eg N, S, E, W in weather reports for enum instances with names NORTH, SOUTH, EAST, WEST, and having to deal with converting them to/from these values. The enum may have other fields, but almost always they are serialized using exactly one of them. Regarding "changing the constructor", you only have to add 1 line to an already-required constructor. I use this pattern frequently, and I'm comfortable that it's "good code".

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to tell me. The “other fields” are completely irrelevant, regardless of whether you search linearly or using a hash lookup. But to stay at your `NORTH, SOUTH, EAST, WEST` example, the worst thing that can happen in a linear search is having three additional string comparisons, all of them stopping at or even before the first character whereas the worst thing that happens in a hash lookup is having to calculate a not yet cached hashcode, incorporating *all* characters. so the hash lookup is not necessarily cheaper than a linear search.

Comment: hash lookup would be cheaper than a  linear search if you had enough constants, but the big problem here is that the inner class thing is useless because it will not lazy initialize due to the constructor access.

Comment: @markus there is no "problem" here, and it is  not actually lazy initialization, but it's pretty close: since we need the map initialized before the first call to the constructor, it's lazy but occurs immediately. The class loader ensures all inner static classes are initialized *before* the class itself is initialized - that's how we get around enum's initialization rule that all instances are initialized before any of its static fields.

Comment: bohemian try my version, it only initializes the map just before the call to "fromFriendlyValue"

Answer (score -1):

```
public enum Foo {

  BAR_1("Bar 1"),
  BAR_2("Bar 2");

  private static class Holder {
    static Map<String, Foo> map = new HashMap<String, Foo>()
       {{
         for(Foo f:Foo.values())
         {
            put(f.getFriendlyValue(),f);
         }
       }};
  }

  private String friendlyValue;

  Foo(String friendlyValue){
    this.friendlyValue = friendlyValue;
  }

  public String getFriendlyValue() {
    return friendlyValue;
  }

  public static Foo fromFriendlyValue(String friendlyValue){
    return Holder.map.get(friendlyValue);
  }
}
```

This lazy initializes , unlike @bohemian's solution. And the magic here is an anonymous class extending hashmap, executing its anynymous constructor to loop all values of Foo into the map.

Although for most enums (which have a very limited amount of constants) , the simplest solution is just  to loop them all.

```
public enum Foo {

  BAR_1("Bar 1"),
  BAR_2("Bar 2");

  private String friendlyValue;

  Foo(String friendlyValue){
    this.friendlyValue = friendlyValue;
  }

  public String getFriendlyValue() {
    return friendlyValue;
  }

  public static Foo fromFriendlyValue(String friendlyValue){
    for(Foo f:Foo.values())
    {
      if(f.getFriendlyValue().equals(friendlyValue))
          return f;
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```

Since the cost of just doing the comparison is next to nothing for small enums.

Comment: It seems like quite a waste to have 2 inner classes... @Bohemian's solution handles processor and memory efficiency a bit better.

Comment: yeah but it doesnt lazy initialize.

Comment: I usually use just a loop for these, since most enums are so small that the O(n) cost doesnt really mean anything.

Comment: You might want to improve it by moving the anonymous class body to a `static { }` initializer; double-brace initialization syntax is usually considered a bad coding practice.

Comment: oh. I think it looks cleaner than a static{} since it attaches to the immediate code it is initializing.Besides a constructor is a constructor, a static{} is a static{}